# Excel Data Model - Creating a many-to-one summary table by mapping table and column names

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, dax, calculated-field

I am trying to create a summary calculation on a set of tables which I have added to an Excel data model. I have 5 tables with the following columns:

- Datetime (UTC)
- Measured Data 1
- Simulated Data 1
- Measured Data 2
- Simulated Data 2
- etc.

I have created a master Date-time table which links these 5 tables together on their UTC date-time column.

My query is how to optimally create calculated fields on each of these tables without needing to explicitly specify the calculations on each individual table, as is the case with PivotTables (I need to select the specific measured and simulated data columns from one individual table in the data model). Instead I would like to be able to map all measured fields to one column and all simulated fields to another, and then use filters to select out the fields (or groups of fields) I want to compare.

I started by creating a summary table which lists all my tables in my data model by name along with the names of measured and simulated columns within each. However, I'm unsure what the next step should be. This seems like a pretty straightforward problem, but it has me stumped this morning. I'd appreciate any help. Let me know if I haven't fully explained anything.